# WinMerge in Android Studio and git shows entire file as changed

Tags: git, android-studio, winmerge

I use WinMerge successfully in Visual Studio with the following params:

```
/e /u /maximize %1 %2
```

But when using WinMerge as an external diff tool in AS, it shows me the entire file as one big difference even though it might have several small differences that are clear to see.

I would like WinMerge to show me each difference in place as it does in Visual Studio or any other simple diff between similar files.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in some other forum:

In WinMerge Options, check the option "Ignore carriage return differences (Windows/Unix/Mac)".

Now WinMerge is working as expected!